# javascript error, A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have used some jquery components in my web site, Suddenly i'm getting an error,

"A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.
"

I have used, Jquery tab component, Carousel components 5 times, image slider component. Is it due to many Jquery compnents?

I have used,

jquery-1.6.4.min.js

Comment: usually this happens with jQuery plugins. I know one such plugin "InGrid" , which never loaded. better find different plugin or try in a faster system.

Comment: It's due to *a particular [plugin or] something* taking too long to yield execution back to the JS runtime. It's *not* caused by the *number* of plugins, although there *could* be interactions in play. First thing to do to fix this is to find out which code is the culprit...

Comment: In which browser you are getting this error? I got this in IE. This is because some of the selectors of jquery makes the proccessing slow

Comment: @user850234 - It was in Firefox, and same thing happens on every browser but Firefox only fired the message. Yes it should be selectors, Bz when i changed the order of some scripts, it works, Given below the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the error,

Issue was the order of some jquery scripts. Once its in the correct order, it works without any issue, not due to too many components.

@madhairsilence and @pst - Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0):

Problem in Firefox,

Disable firefox add on and restart firefox with safe mode...

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1008123